# Como faço para sempre manter minhas URLs em letras minúsculas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, iis, url

Quero que todas as URLs do meu site fiquem em minúsculas para ajudar no SEO e para que o compartilhamento de links fique consistente.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). Para usar em um servidor basta baixar e instalar. Shared hosts normalmente incluem este modulo.

Com este modulo instalado basta configurar regras.

Para converter tudo para minusculo é possível utilizar esta regra.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rule name="LowerCase" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="GET" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rewrite>
```

Ela irá detectar se há letras maiúsculas na URL, em caso positivo irá redirecionar para o equivalente em minusculo. Note que esta regra só redireciona o método `GET`, evitando assim que impeça o envio de um formulário ou um *request* externo incorreto.

E para que seu código gere URLs em minusculo você deve seta a seguinte propriedade para `true` (disponível apenas no .NET 4.5):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
}
```

---

Caso você não tenha o IIS URL Rewrite você pode fazer por código, no `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(Request.Url.OriginalString, @"[A-Z]"
        && HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.OriginalString.ToLower());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: É realmente necessário escrever aquela? Eu costumo apenas definir `RouteCollection.LowercaseUrls` como `true` e obtenho o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso um metodo um pouco diferente pra fazer, e evito modificar o QueryString pra evitar problemas, as vezes o parametro pode ser necessário case sensitive ou caso seja um bundle ou urls que podem ser sensivas a case sensitive e não fazem diferença no que o usuário visualiza

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var isGet = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestType.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("get");
        if (!isGet || HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains(".")) return; // não desejo redirecionar em caso de POST, ou imagens/css/js/etc
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/Content/") || HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/Scripts/") || HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/bundles/") || HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/lightview/")) return; // proteção adicional ao arquivos das pastas content (css) e scripts (js)
        var lowercaseUrl = (Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(lowercaseUrl, @"[A-Z]")) return;
        lowercaseUrl = lowercaseUrl.ToLower() + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query; // Não devo alterar o case da querystring
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
        Response.AddHeader("Location", lowercaseUrl);
        Response.End();
    }      

}
```

Isso me evita alguns problemas e deixa somente o necessário no padrão.
Adiciono também o cabeçalho 301 pra não ter problemas com o Google